# Navigate to a SplitViewController

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, ipad, uinavigationcontroller, iphone-sdk-3.2

I've been playing around with the iPad SDK looking for ways to improve my current iPhone app. I've got a couple place where I think the new "SplitView" would look pretty good. My question is if it's possible to navigate to a "SplitView" with my current navigation based application? Mainly I'm not sure how to push that SplitViewController onto my current stack of views. Any thoughts?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It should always be the root controller according to Apple.

> The split view controller’s view
>   should always be installed as the root
>   view of your application window. You
>   should never present a split view
>   inside of a navigation or tab bar
>   interface.

Answer (score 0):

Check out the [Multiple Detail Views](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/samplecode/MultipleDetailViews/Introduction/Intro.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40009775) sample app on Apple's Documentation, this could give you a good idea on how to deal with navigation structure and how to display views on the "splitViewController".

Answer (score 0):

You can use a UISplitViewController in a UITabBarController without any problems.  I have not attempted to push a UISplitViewController into an UINavigationController however.

Answer (score 0):

(At least) with iOS 8 (which runs on any ipad except the first one) it's possible to use a "present modally"-segue to display a splitviewcontroller.

Drawback is that an existing navigation bar isn't displayed.