# UISplitViewController

Tags: iphone, uisplitviewcontroller

I want to navigate from a Tableviewcontroller to a new site which contains a splittview.

So i created an UIViewController and added the splitview with the IB. 
My question is: How can I add the splittView to the View of my UIViewController?

or is it only possible to add a splittview out of an appdelegate?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2633532/navigate-to-a-splitviewcontroller) will help? A `UISplitViewController` must be the root view controller of your application

Comment: Ok, Thank you. And there is no change that the UISplitviewcontroller is not the root view?

Comment: You could always make your own split viewController. But the UISplitViewController must be the root viewController of your entire application