# Can I have a SplitViewController inside a TabBarViewController(iOS 9.0 +)?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitabbarcontroller, uisplitviewcontroller

I have an app with `UITabBarViewController` as rootviewcontroller. On some tab item, I want to have a SplitViewController inside a `UITabbarViewController`.
So here my `UISplitViewController` will become a childViewController for TabbarVC.

Will this be allowed? Are there any Apple guidelines suggesting not to do this?

As I see, they are suggesting to put SplitVC as RootVC. But many applications have already done what we are doing now.

Answer (score 0):

[Answers here might](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2633532/navigate-to-a-splitviewcontroller) help Apple recommends UISplitViewController should always be the rootviewcontroller

I had nearly same scenario of creating a `UISplitViewController` inside a view controller. So I created my own custom SplitViewController

Here is the note from apple

> You cannot push a split view controller onto a navigation stack. Although it is possible to install a split view controller as a child in some other container view controllers, doing is not recommended in most cases. Split view controllers are normally installed at the root of your app’s window.

Answer (score 0):

Apple HIG recommends to have tab bar as the root or split view controller as root. But I still achieved this by putting in a container for one of the tab bar's child view controller. And as a result, you can load split view controller into the container view of any view controller, irrespective of whether its tab bar or a normal view controller.